# Unit radial vector field

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Lee's book defines the unit radial vector field in normal coordinates as

$$ \partial_r:= \frac{x^i}{r(x)} \partial_i$$

and $r(x):=\sqrt{\sum_i (x^i)^2}$

Now this is a unit vector field iff $$g(\partial_r,\partial_r)=1.$$

By linearity this is equivalent to $$1= \frac{x^iy^j}{r^2} g(\partial_i,\partial_j).$$

Is there now any reason that this should hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the very next page, Proposition 5.11(e) shows that it is always a unit vector field.

Comment: alright, got it. We only need to verify it at the origin, where the metric tensor is the identity, since we can represent $\partial_r$ as the derivative of the geodesic(!) $\gamma(t) = t \frac{x^i}{r} \partial_i$ in normal coordinates, i.e. the speed is preserved. I like your book.